# Removing item from a listbox that is binding to a database table

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net

i. I have a form that allow users add multiple phone numbers using a listbox and two buttons to add to the listbox and to remove from the listbox if they make a mistake and want to correct it before saving to the phone number table in the database.

ii. I have another form which allows them to edit what has been saved, which means they can either remove or add more as the case maybe.

The first (i) works perfectly well while the second (ii) does not. What I discovered is that i can only remove what I added but not what is coming from the database table. How do I do that?

Below is my code sample for the second form (ii):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
                    Contact_Phone(getId)
                End If
    end sub

 Private Sub Contact_Phone(ByVal FK_CID As Integer)
        Dim strSQL As String
        strSQL = "Select PK_PNID,PN_Number From tblPhoneNumber where FK_CID=" & FK_CID
        With cClass
            .BindListBox(Me.lbPhone, strSQL, "PN_Number", "PK_PNID")
        End With
    End Sub
 Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Try
            Me.lbPhone.Items.Remove(Me.lbPhone.SelectedItem.Text)
        Catch ex As Exception
            If ex.Message = "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Me.lblErr.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            Me.lblErr.Text = ex.Message
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When in the form(ii) an user is deleting a phone number, just delete it from the db, so next time when the phone numbers are shown in the form(ii) the deleted phone number will not be there.

If you do not want to make a post back on delete button click(which will erase the user added phone numbers in the list box as it has not been saved to the db till now), then make an AJAX call to the sever passing the values and delete the number.

Comment: I don't want the update to occur when the remove button is clicked. I have a separate button for update after the user must have added or remove from the list.

Comment: @uikrosoft - so in the update button you update all the phone numbers, i mean add new ones added by the user and delete the deleted ones form the db.